# Overfull \hbox warning - two plots side-by-side

Tags: subfloats, minipage, psfrag

I am trying to create an environment for plotting two figures side-by-side:

```
    \begin{figure}[t] 
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
            \flushleft
                \psfragfig[frame,mode=nonstop]{Plot_random_Breite_05_1}
                    \caption{Figur Nr. 8a} 
                    \label{fig:8a}
        \end{minipage}
\hspace*{14pt}% separation between the subfigures
        \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
            \flushleft
                \psfragfig[frame,mode=nonstop]{Plot_random_Breite_05_2}
                    \caption{Figur Nr. 8b} 
                     \label{fig:8b}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

Unfortunately I get an "Overfull hbox" warning.

I tried several things to remove this warning:

- remove `\hspace`
- smaller width (`0.4\textwidth`)
- `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth`
- `subfigure` instead of `minipage`

Nothing helped. The plot is not scaled, the textwidth is about 9cm and the size of the plot is about 3cm.

Has someone an idea? Can't figure out where the bug is -.-

If I use `\hfill` as recommended below, my code and the output look like this:

```
\begin{figure}[t] 
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \raggedright
            \psfragfig[frame,mode=nonstop]{Plot_random_Breite_05_1}
                \caption{Figur Nr. 8a} 
                \label{fig:8a}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
     \begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \raggedleft
            \psfragfig[frame,mode=nonstop]{Plot_random_Breite_05_2}
                \caption{Figur Nr. 8b} 
                 \label{fig:8b}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

As you can see I would prefer, if both picture `align` with the margins.

**Is there a way to `align` the second caption with the frame of the plot?**

Comment: Between the two subfigures you have a normal space (the end-of-line after `\end{minipage}`) and 14pt. Remove `\hspace*{14pt}` and put `\hfill` after `\end{minipage}` (same line, no space in between). By the way you should use `\raggedright`, not `\flushleft`.

Comment: please don't edit the question to ask a completely different question, it makes the existing answers impossible to understand, best to ask a new question, but the normal thing to do is use \centering for captions but yours appear to be flush left, probably due to code you have not shown. It is always best to post _complete_ documents that show the issue (use `\includegraphics[]{example-image}` which is an image in most distributions, to make your example portable.

Comment: The caption package has justification=raggedright and justification=raggedleft options.  You can call \captionsetup inside each minipage.

Answer (score 2):

The construction on the line that contains your two sub-figures consist of elements that have the following widths:

1. A `minipage` of width `0.49\textwidth`;
2. An inter-word space between the first `minipage` and the `\hspace*`;
3. A *hard* space of `14pt`;
4. A `minipage` of width `0.49\textwidth`.

The above combination is wider than `\textwidth`, obviously, as is indicated by the first construction below (I'm using `\rule` instead of `minipage`, but the effect is the same):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  X \dotfill X% For reference

  \rule{0.49\textwidth}{1pt}
  \hspace*{14pt}% Separation between sub-figures
  \rule{0.49\textwidth}{1pt}

  \rule{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-7pt}{1pt}%
  \hspace*{14pt}% Separation between sub-figures
  \rule{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-7pt}{1pt}

  \rule{0.49\textwidth}{1pt}
  \hfill% Flexible fill between sub-figures
  \rule{0.49\textwidth}{1pt}

  X \dotfill X% For reference
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If you're stuck on having the *fixed* `14pt` gap between the two sub-figures, then you need to make sure that each component is exactly split between the remainder. That is, each image (or `minipage`) takes up `0.5\textwidth-7pt`. That's what the second construction achieves.

[Note the use of `%` sign after the first sub-figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764) in order to avoid the inter-word space that is naturally inserted after a macro with an argument.

---

Alternatively, if you're interested in fixing the width of the sub-figures (rather than the `14pt` gap mentioned above), then you can insert a flexible fill using `\hfill`.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted enough information to completely diagnose the problem but

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{14pt}% separation between the subfigures
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
\end{minipage}
```

is a line `.98\textwidth` + 1 word space + `14pt` wide so that may or may not be wider than `\textwidth`.

Perhaps you want

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
\end{minipage}\hfill 
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
\end{minipage}
```

which will have exactly `.02\textwidth` space between the `minipage`s, with a total line width of exactly `\textwidth`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast comments and the explanation! I think there was a big error in reasoning ;-) I have tried your suggestions already and edited my post above with a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to play with XXX. In my case, 0.497 worked perfectly!

```
\begin{figure}[t] 
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.XXX\textwidth}
    \raggedright
        \psfragfig[frame,mode=nonstop]{Plot_random_Breite_05_1}
            \caption{Figur Nr. 8a} 
            \label{fig:8a}
\end{minipage}\hfill
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.XXX\textwidth}
    \raggedleft
        \psfragfig[frame,mode=nonstop]{Plot_random_Breite_05_2}
            \caption{Figur Nr. 8b} 
             \label{fig:8b}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```